# When does list[n] == list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I was reading some code and came across a line that read `if len(list)==1 and list[0] == list:`, where list is a list of all numbers. I presumed a one-element list is equal to that one element when reading the code, but when I tried `[0] == 0`, it returned `False`. What does the "if" statement mean then?

Comment: `a = []; a.append(a)`?

Comment: Very nice tobias- also a custom class that subclasses list and redefines `__eq__`

Comment: Doesn't apply to `list`s, but for Python `str` this will happen for length one strings; `'a'[0] == 'a'`. Given the name is `list` this probably doesn't apply, but figured I'd mention it in case it does apply to someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list can contain a reference to itself:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(lst)
>>> print(lst)
[[...]]
>>> lst[0] == lst
True
```

The same is of course also true for other container types, but not as easy, as e.g. a `set` can not contain another `set` (at least not directly) and `tuple` or `frozenset` do not allow adding elements after their creation (again, at least not directly).

Comment: This isn't OP's question, but when might this be useful?

Comment: While this answers my original question, upon further review of the source code, I can confirm that the list does not contain any self references (only numbers)

Comment: @jakub Maybe you are using the lists to form a directed cyclic graph, although there'd certainly be better ways to do that.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy No idea, I'd say that's an error in the code and the condition right of the `or` is actually never needed.

Comment: @tobias_k yep that was it.

Answer (score 0):

No practical need for this, but...

```
class MyList(list):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

list = MyList([1,2])
print(list)
print(list[0] == list)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2]
True
```

Comment: I suppose while this technically works, I was asking about a basic list rather than a subclass

Comment: @nii75435eoopy Show us the context of where you read the original code